# Subset dataframe on presence of certain value in any column

Tags: r, filter, subset

I have an (embarrassingly) simple question: how to filter or subset a dataframe on a single value in any column of the dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
  v1 = c(1:10),
  v2 = c(10:1),
  v3 = c(1,3,2,9,5,6,1,2,3,9)
)
```

Say, I want to subset `df`on those rows that, in any column, contain the value `9`. I can do this like this:

```
df[df[,1]==9|df[,2]==9|df[,3]==9,]
   v1 v2 v3
2   2  9  3
4   4  7  9
9   9  2  3
10 10  1  9
```

But such a convoluted code for such a trivial task! There must be more efficient ways, either in `base R`or other packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

additional solution:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  v1 = c(1:10),
  v2 = c(10:1),
  v3 = c(1,3,2,9,5,6,1,2,3,9)
)

df[apply(df, 1, function(x) any(x == 9)), ]
#>    v1 v2 v3
#> 2   2  9  3
#> 4   4  7  9
#> 9   9  2  3
#> 10 10  1  9
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

using **tidyverse**

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(any(c_across(everything()) == 9))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#> # Rowwise: 
#>      v1    v2    v3
#>   <int> <int> <dbl>
#> 1     2     9     3
#> 2     4     7     9
#> 3     9     2     3
#> 4    10     1     9
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Use `rowSums` :

```
subset(df, rowSums(df == 9, na.rm = TRUE) > 0)

#   v1 v2 v3
#2   2  9  3
#4   4  7  9
#9   9  2  3
#10 10  1  9
```